# Statically linking screen_capture_lite in Rust

Tags: rust, cmake

I am attempting to write a Rust wrapper for [screen_capture_lite](https://github.com/smasherprog/screen_capture_lite), my code for which is located [here](https://github.com/ScottyThePilot/screen_capture_lite). I've gotten the cmake crate compiling screen_capture_lite from source, but I get 'unresolved external symbol' linker errors when trying to run my `window_count` example script. These errors appear to be for Windows API symbols or C++ standard library symbols. [Here is a pastebin with the errors](https://pastebin.com/mE05TG80).

From what I've figured out about linking, I assume this is because I'm trying to statically link to screen_capture_lite, which gets rid of screen_capture_lite's dynamic dependencies. This seems true, because when I link to all of the system libraries manually, my `window_count` example script works and correctly reports the number of open windows. This is what my build script looks like when I do that:

```rust
extern crate cmake;

use cmake::Config;

fn main() {
  let dest = Config::new(".").profile("Release").build();
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", dest.join("lib").display());
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=screen_capture_lite");

  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=kernel32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=user32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gdi32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=winspool");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=shell32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ole32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=oleaut32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=uuid");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=comdlg32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=advapi32");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dwmapi");
}
```

Manually linking the system libraries doesn't seem like a good solution to me, so is there a way to export a list of paths from cmake to a file for my build script to consume?